# I'm trying to update 2 fields in multiple tables in my database using a trigger after inserting a new row

Tags: oracle, plsql

i just created the trigger

here is the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_update_solde_nbreserv
AFTER INSERT ON reservation
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE CLIENTS
    SET CLIENTS.NB_RESERV = NB_RESERV+1 , CLIENTS.SOLDE = SOLDE+1
    FROM dbo.clients as c
    INNER JOIN dbo.reservation as r
    ON c.numc = r.numc
    WHERE r.numr = :new.numr;
          
    BEGIN
        SELECT fillHist_station FROM DUAL;
    END;
    
end tr_update_solde_nbreserv;
```

i'm getting these 2 errors:

> Error(1,9): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
>
> Error(3,9): PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

how can i fix them

Comment: Not the first error, but do you have a `dbo` schema? Also, syntax for `update` is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/UPDATE.html). I'm not sure where `INNER JOIN` fits in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your trigger code.

1) The purpose of this part of the code is unclear :

```
BEGIN
    SELECT fillHist_station FROM DUAL;
END;
```

`fillHist_station` is not declared, hence this code would raise an `invalid identifier` error.

2) The syntax of the `UPDATE` query is invalid. Also, your intend is to select from the table that the trigger fired on, which is not allowed in Oracle. From looking at your code, it looks like you don't actually need to query `RESERVATION` to achieve your goal. As a row was just inserted in `RESERVATION`, you already know the corresponding client number.

3) You miss a `/` at the end

Here is an updated version of your code, that you can play around with in [this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e9a53476cb9c327ef403e26c1dbe9441) (you did not provide the structure of your tables so I just created the coulmns that are referenced in the query) :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_update_solde_nbreserv
AFTER INSERT ON RESERVATION
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
    UPDATE CLIENTS
    SET NB_RESERV = NB_RESERV+1 , SOLDE = SOLDE+1
    WHERE numc = :new.numc; 
END tr_update_solde_nbreserv;
/
```

Comment: i just need to update the fields of the client that did the reservation  here are my 2 tables:


    **CLIENTS(numc(primarykey), name,address, tel, solde , nb_reserve(nbre of reservations) )**


 **RESERVATION(numr(primary key), numc , id_chambre, dater, datedeb, datefin)**

Comment: @daniel : well, that's what this trigger is supposed do. Can you please test it (or have a look at the db fiddle) and let me know if it works for you ?

Comment: Welcome @daniel !

Answer (score 1):

```
update CLIENTS
    SET CLIENTS.NB_RESERV = NB_RESERV+1 , CLIENTS.SOLDE = SOLDE+1
    FROM dbo.clients as c
    inner join dbo.reservation as r
        on c.numc = r.numc
        where r.numr = :new.numr;
```

update with inner join is not supported in Oracle database in this way. furthermore `dbo.clients` and `dbo.reservations` look like Sql Server tables rather then oracle.

I believe that you are looking for something like this, but I am not sure about the relations. You may need to fix the query.

```
UPDATE 
(
   SELECT clients.nb_reserv, r.nb_reserv as r_nb_reserv, clients.solde, r.solde as r_solde 
   FROM clients
   inner join reservation as r
     on c.numc = r.numc
   where r.numr = :new.numr
) t
SET CLIENTS.NB_RESERV = r_nb_reserv + 1, clients.solde = r_solde+1;
```

Simpler approach

```
UPDATE clients SET NB_RESERV = (SELECT nb_reserv +1
                                  FROM reservations 
                                  WHERE c.numc = r.numc and r.numr = :new.numr),
    SOLDE = (SELECT SOLDE +1
                                  FROM reservations 
                                  WHERE c.numc = r.numc and r.numr = :new.numr)
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM reservations 
     WHERE c.numc = r.numc and r.numr = :new.numr);
```

Comment: I worked on it but I am not sure about your relationships, so you may need to work on it

Comment: my only problem is that the fields i need to update are in the clients table and i need to update them when a row in the reservation table is inserted  here are the tables withe their fields:     

  CLIENTS(numc(primarykey), name,address, tel, solde , nb_reserve(nbre of reservations) )

RESERVATION(numr(primary key), numc , id_chambre, dater, datedeb, datefin)